# Could my AI classifier be extended to categorical data?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, k-nn, ai

I created a new AI classifier.

[Physics Based Classifier](http://barrettduna.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/physics_AI_algorithm.pdf)

Comment: Interesting but I'm not sure if this is on-topic here, in general DataScienceSE is not a research forum. From a quick look a few suggestions: (1) Submit your work to a ML journal or conference, peer review is much better than feedback from random strangers on the internet; (2) you should compare the performance of your new method against state of the art methods on some benchmark datasets, and if possible prove that your method is at least as good as the others; (3) not as important but quite important: you could add a study of the efficiency of the new method, especially the training stage.